# How to split single list element in to multiple elements based on a separator

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I know there are a lot of similar questions but my use-case is unique. The following is my list `['apple,mango,fig']`. What I want is to split the single element into multiple list elements based on `","`. My final list should be like this `['apple','mango','fig']`. As far as I know we can convert it into sub-list using `split()` method. But can I convert it into different elements of the same list? Is this possible?

Comment: Yes, you can use `split()` here as well. If you had tried, you wouldn't want to ask a question.

Comment: Use ```split()``` for splitting list.\n **Please do try first, and share the code where you are facing problem, Just asking solution will not help.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If there is only one element in the list:

```
print(l[0].split(','))
```

If there are multiple elements in the list, use:

```
print([x for i in l for x in i.split(',')])
```

Comment: That's elegant! I had a normal list that had elements that needed splitting by a delimiter while retaining in the same list.